# Maven: build Scala code and Java code together into a Fat JAR

Tags: java, scala, maven

I have a Scala project that I build into a Fat JAR. Today I needed to add some Java classes to the project but now my Maven build is failing.

My project structure looks (roughly) like this:

```
.
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── resources
│       │   └── Log4j.properties
|       ├── java
│       │   └── com
│       │       └── myorg
│       │           └── myproject
│       │               └── MyPublicJavaClass.java
│       └── scala
│           └── com
│               └── myorg
│                   └── myproject
│                       └── spark
│                           └── Main.scala
└── pom.xml
```

And here's what my POM file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <name>myproject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <groupId>com.myorg</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.1.0-RELEASE</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <scala.tools.version>2.11</scala.tools.version>
    <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
    <spark.version>2.4.0</spark.version>
    <aws.sdk.version>1.11.553</aws.sdk.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>

    <plugins>
      <!-- I added this plugin today to try and make it compile the Java code -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>src/main/java</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <!-- This compiles the Scala code -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <!-- This builds the fat JAR -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.myorg.myproject.spark.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.tools.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.tools.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
      <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
      <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazon.emr</groupId>
      <artifactId>emr-dynamodb-hadoop</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.scopt</groupId>
      <artifactId>scopt_${scala.tools.version}</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-scala</artifactId>
      <version>11.0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Before I added the Java class, along with the `build-helper-maven-plugin` today, Maven was able to build this project without any problems. But now, it seems I haven't configured that plugin correctly, or perhaps I'm not using the right one?

My Scala code is trying to use an object of type `MyPublicJavaClass` so now the build errors I see in Maven look like this:

> [ERROR] ~/src/main/scala/com/myorg/myproject/spark/Main.scala:227: error: not found: type MyPublicJavaClass
>
> ...
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:compile (default) on project myproject: wrap: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1(Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

I thought that the `build-helper-maven-plugin` would tell it to add the Java code's source directory to the list of sources to generate before compile time, but apparently not. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a very old plugin for your Scala compilation (last version `2.15.2` have been released [Feb 6 2011](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-tools/maven-scala-plugin/2.15.2)).

I suggest you first to upgrade to a more recent plugin, like [`scala-maven-plugin`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.alchim31.maven/scala-maven-plugin/4.0.2) (latest release `4.0.2` on May 11 2019).

You can then found an example with mixed Scala/Java sources [in the docs](http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/example_java.html). There is no need to use `build-helper-maven-plugin` in this case, nor to configure `sourceDirectory` and `testSourceDirectory`. Check this simple `pom.xml` with this plugin (I have just removed the unused dependencies from the example you have provided when I reproduced the problem locally) :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <name>myproject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <groupId>com.myorg</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.1.0-RELEASE</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <scala.tools.version>2.11</scala.tools.version>
    <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>scala-compile-first</id>
              <phase>process-resources</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
                <goal>compile</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
              <id>scala-test-compile</id>
              <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
              </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <!-- This builds the fat JAR -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.myorg.myproject.spark.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Perfect, the combination of three things you recommended did the trick: (1) switching from (old) maven-scala-plugin to (new) scala-maven-plugin, (2) removing the build-helper-maven-plugin, and (3) removing the sourceDirectory, testSourceDirectory, etc. tags.